Which scope should I use to create google meeting link with google calendar API?
I am confusing between these 2 scopes :
1- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
2- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
But I need to create google meeting link ONLY.
Which scope should I use ?
I tried the first scope and it was working but I need to use specific scope so that google can accept verification of it.
